# Possible to pass several array items using 1 attribute?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a group of tick boxes with 1 select all box at the top

```
<input type="checkbox" id="1195" value="All" />

<input type="checkbox" name="GroupA" title="TickboxA" value="TickboxA" id="TickboxA" />
<input type="checkbox" name="GroupA" title="TickboxB" value="TickboxB" id="TickboxB" />
<input type="checkbox" name="GroupA" title="TickboxC" value="TickboxC" id="TickboxC" />
<input type="checkbox" name="GroupA" title="TickboxD" value="TickboxD" id="TickboxD" />
```

I'm passing all the checks to an array so I can pass it around the site like so:

```
$('input').on('ifClicked', function (event) {
    addRemoveService(document.getElementById(this.title));
    setItemArray();
    document.getElementById('mydoc').value = "";
    for (var i = 0; i < itemIdArray.length; i++) {
        setInterestedIn(i);
    }
});
```

I have some jquery that will tick all the boxes for me if i click on the top checkbox - Everything is working perfect, except if i tick on the 'all' checkbox - I can't pass all the titles of all the other boxes to the array - what I want to do is something like:

```
<input type="checkbox" id="1195" value="All" title="TickboxA,TickboxB,TickboxC,TickboxD" />
```

If that makes sense? Is there an easy way to do this?

Comment: If you have a function that loops through your checkboxes and combines the list of selected items into a comma-separated list, why wouldn't that logic work the same when you check "All"?  It may help to show what's going on in those other functions.  Can you provide a self-contained [**Fiddle**](http://www.rubular.com/r/gujTvWYdRb) demonstrating the problem?

Comment: If you're going to pass an array using a DOM element you should really use .data() instead of attributes: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.data/ This way you can store the actual object.